# Sorting a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [filters] => Array ( [filter_1] => 1 
                                            [filter_2] => 1 
                                            [filter_3] => 1 
                                            [filter_4] => 1 
                                            [filter_5] => 1 
                                            [filter_6] => 1 ), 
                       [count]   => 2),

        [1] => Array ( [filters] => Array ( [filter_1] => 1 
                                            [filter_2] => 1 
                                            [filter_3] => 1 
                                            [filter_4] => 1 
                                            [filter_5] => 1 
                                            [filter_6] => 1 ), 
                       [count]   => 34)

        [2] => Array ( [filters] => Array ( [filter_1] => 1 
                                            [filter_2] => 1 
                                            [filter_3] => 1 
                                            [filter_4] => 1 
                                            [filter_5] => 1 
                                            [filter_6] => 1 ), 
                        [count]   => 7)
```

Is it possible to sort the main array keys by the [count] key in each, descending? So that they are in the following order: 1 -2 -0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely want the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.  You can define how the sort function determines which is larger or smaller.

If it's alright that each sub-array (of "filters" and "count") gets re-indexed, this should work perfectly.  By re-indexed, I mean the newly sorted array would start at 0, progress to 1, etc.  This is almost always how you want it, unless your original array is associative.

For example:

```
usort($array, "byCount");

function byCount($a, $b)
{
    if( $a['count'] == $b['count'] )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['count'] < $b['count']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: You could just use `uasort` to maintain key associations

Comment: @Jack Murdoch, assuming @soren would ever want to access the array by index, `uasort` would be the exact opposite of what he would want.  If `$array[0]` got sorted after `$array[1]`, the resulting array would be `$array( 1, 0 )` which is rarely useful, unless, like I mentioned in my answer, the array is associative.

Comment: @rockerest Agreed, the only reason that I included this was because the OP mentioned that he wanted them to end up in the order "1 -2 -0".

Comment: @Jack, that's a good point.  I kind of glossed over that.  I'm assuming that was just an example to show how he would want it to sort, but you bring up a good point.

Comment: @rockerest He accepted yours, so obviously it was just for example ;)

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use the [`uasort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function. Try something like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a["count"] == $b["count"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["count"] > $b["count"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');
```