# How can i re-order an array from 0 to 10 with a value within the array?

Tags: php, arrays, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626648/sorting-a-multidimensional-array)

I have an a multi dimesional associative array:

```
[book]=>{
            [names]=>{
                        [name]=>'thing1',
                        [age]=>'23',
                        [nOrder]=>'1'
                     },
                     {
                        [name]=>'thing2',
                        [age]=>'24',
                        [nOrder]=>'3'
                     },
                     {
                        [name]=>'thing3',
                        [age]=>'25',
                        [nOrder]=>'2'
                     }
        }
```

Hope that example looks ok, basically I need to re-order the positions of the rows within the "names" value to be in order form 1 to 3 by whatever is in the "nOrder" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function cmp( $a, $b ) {
    return $a['nOrder'] > $b['nOrder'] ? 1 : -1;
}

usort( $book['names'], 'cmp' );
```

from [usort manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> This function will sort an array by its values using a user-supplied comparison function. If the array you wish to sort needs to be sorted by some non-trivial criteria, you should use this function.

We pass `cmp` as the comparison function to `usort()` and it will sort elements of `$book['names']` array using that comparison function.

Comment: I dont understand whats going on there, can you explain it? And ive tried the code, but its claiming my array is not an array.

Comment: grr I can't make it work. :( it keeps claiming my array which was good enough for json_encode is NOT an array.

Comment: this is the full function, if you could have a look? http://pastebin.com/jgr5wu4k

Comment: @Ezra `var_dump( $yourArray );` see what you get.

Comment: "Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"

Comment: I get this, i presume this is corrent? http://pastebin.com/M1BLqHvm forgive me for not answering as quickly as id like, stack is mega hanging while loading..